# How would I update a table everytime a specific attribute is updated? (lambda, maybe?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, lambda

So I created a new table to keep track of everytime a project in another table switches from active to inactive. I've successfully been able to add ALL of the projects and their active statuses but that isn't what I want.

```
#Here is the code for the status change table 
class CreateActiveHistories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2] def change create_table :active_histories do |t| t.string :project t.string :active t.timestamps t.string :user end end end
and here is the code for the projects table these are just the attributes that I feel like are necessary to make my table work.
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.references :customer, foreign_key: true
      t.string :name
      t.string :harvest_project_id
      t.date :start_date
      t.date :end_date
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

#and adding the active column 
class AddActiveToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :projects, :active, :boolean, default: true
  end
end

#this is the code I have in my table currently for the active status 
<td><%= project.name %></td>
<td><%= project_status %></td>

#This is my controller
def active_history
    @project = Project.where(id: params[:id]).includes(:customer).take

    @q = Project.ransack(params[:q])
    @q.active_eq = true unless params[:q]
    @projects = @q.result.includes(:customer, :project_hours, project_requirements: [:resource_requirements])
    @project_names = Project.all.pluck(:name).uniq.sort

    if @q.active_eq == true
      @active = '1'
    elsif @q.active_eq == false
      @active = '0'
    else
      @active = '-1'
    end


  end 

#and this is in my helper
  def project_status
    if @project.active == false
      return "Active"
    else
      return "Inactive" 
    end
  end
```

So, would I create a lambda that updates that table every time I want that table to update? This seems like it would be my best option but I have never used a lambda anywhere other than AWS and it's pretty much automized for you on there... SO ruby-railists... How would I do this on rails?

Comment: Are you asking about how to create an entry in the ActiveyHistory table? Does an ActiveHistory record belong_to a project?  It looks like project is just a string on that table.  But either way, when a project switches its status you could just create a new entry and save it in that table, right?  Is there some other part of the process/requirements that I missing?

Comment: I am sorry, but your requirements are unclear to me. Would you mind explaining what you try to achieve and why you want to do that? I only understand that you need to update a certain table when something changes on that table. But why can't you do the update at the same time when the change happens? Would be helpful when you could describe in your own words what needs to happen and why.

Comment: No, active_history is seperate. I want that table to update whenever a new project is added or whenever a project's status changes from active to inactive... I think I have to use active callbacks.

Comment: 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use callbacks." Now they have two problems.' https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial